# Freezing object __proto__ in v8

Tags: javascript, node.js, v8

I was wondering if there were any caveats to `freezing` an object prototype.  I was trying to create an immutable object but found out from the docs that

> values that are objects can still be modified, unless they are also
>   frozen

I am trying to make the `__proto__` property immutable, my initial attempt involved `freeze`ing the instance:

```
$ node --version
v0.12.7
$ node
> function Test() {}
undefined
> Test.prototype = {
...  hi: function() { return 'hello' }
... }
{ hi: [Function] }
> t = Object.freeze(new Test())
{}
> t
{}
> t.hello = 'hi'
'hi'
> t
{}
> t.hi
[Function]
> t.hi()
'hello'
> t.__proto__.hi = 'changed'
'changed'
> t.hi
'changed'
```

---

But when the `prototype` is frozen the `__proto__` object is immutable as expected.

```
> Test.prototype = Object.freeze({
    ...  hi: function() { return 'hello' }
    ... })
```

Now instances of `Test` have an immutable `__proto__` object (observed from shell).  I was wondering **are there any side effects to freezing an object prototype** (perhaps involving multiple instances? or correct object instantiation??).  The target environment is for node.  Thank you

Comment: It’s fine, but what’s the point?

Comment: Of course you forgot to freeze `Object.prototype` or use `Object.freeze(Object.create(null))` for your prototype :-)

Comment: @minitech If there are no side effects, i'd be happy to accept your answer

Comment: Notice that `t.__proto__` is still writeable.

Comment: @MinusFour: No it's not. You cannot change the [[prototype]] of a frozen object.

Comment: @Bergi, well I might have made an assumption that he's no longer freezing the `new Test()` but the prototype.  If he's still freezing the result of the `new` operator then yes, it's not writable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The side effect of freezing a prototype is (tautologically) that the prototype is frozen. Whether that causes problems depends on how your application intends to use the prototype. There is nothing inherently wrong with it as far as the language is concerned. I would even consider it good style, if it wasn't for the fact that VMs sometimes still don't implement frozen objects very efficiently (they can be slower than regular objects under some circumstances, because for historic reasons they are considered a special case).